# Building a discord bot that interacts with a custom API

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm making a bot in python, a discord bot, that interacts with a custom API with the command /chat, that sends the prompt of the /chat + a custom prompt
Here is my code:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="chat", description="Chat with the bot")
async def chat_with_bot(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    prompt = f"Personality: {PERSONALITY}\nBackground: {BACKGROUND}\n"
    prompt += interaction.options['prompt']

    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {API_KEY}"
    }
    data = {
        "model": MODEL,
        "prompt": prompt
    }

    print(f"Prompt: {prompt}")
    print(f"Request data: {data}")

    response = requests.post(API_ENDPOINT, json=data, headers=headers)

    print(f"Response status code: {response.status_code}")
    print(f"Response data: {response.text}")

    if response.status_code == 200:
        output = response.json()["output"]

        print(f"Output: {output}")

        await interaction.response.send_message(output)
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message("Oops! Something went wrong.")
```

i'm having an error on this line

```
    prompt += interaction.options['prompt']
```

this is the error

```
ERROR    discord.app_commands.tree Ignoring exception in command 'chat'    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 828, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\33695\Documents\Python\PAI\botname\test.py", line 45, in chat_with_bot
    prompt += interaction.options['prompt']
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'options'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1248, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 853, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 846, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'chat' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'options'
```

I'm not sure how to proceed, everything is up to date, and my discord bot has the proper authorizations, i did a /hello command and it worked very well!
Thank you very much!

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow.](/tour) The class `discord.Interaction` doesn't have any `options` attribute.